# What is more important number of CUDA cores on GPU or VRAM for video editing and graphics?

Tags: hardware

What is more important number of CUDA cores on GPU or VRAM for video editing and graphics? What are benefits from good graphic card? Better preview when working with 4k files with effects on them?

I am using Adobe Premiere and After Effects, sometimes Davinci Resolve...
Rendering times is not important to me much as smoother preview of 4k files when I edit them on timeline, smaller lagging when I put Magic Bullet Looks or something similar on clips...

Comment: Welcome! Can you be more specific? What are you trying to accomplish? What is important to you in terms of performance and in terms of your workflow?

Comment: I added more content...

Answer (score 2):

It depends entirely on which software you are using, as well as plugins. Adobe Premiere takes advantage of CUDA, which radically increases rendering speeds and playback of specific file types.

But if you've applied filters, or 3rd party plugin filters that do not take advantage of CUDA optimization, your bottleneck will be the speed of your CPU.

Alternatively, certain 3D platforms are only accelerated by NVIDIA cards, others, require AMD.

The amount of VRAM affects how much data the card can handle in one single load (typically 1 frame), which comes into play mostly with 3D work.